# Can we convert Picklist value into Date format?

Tags: formula, formula-field, picklist, date

I have picklist which has date values like 01/01/2016,01/02/2016 ..... I need to Map this picklist value to One formula(date) field.

I have tried with Datevalue(TEXT(picklist_c)) in the formula field, But it didn't work. The format is correct but it is showing on the field `#Error!`

Answer (score 6):

DATEVALUE requires the format to be "YYYY-MM-DD". Since your picklist doesn't match that format, you'd need some extensive code:

```
DATEVALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(picklist),4)&"-"&MID(TEXT(picklist),4,2)&"-"&LEFT(TEXT(picklist),2))
```

Or:

```
DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(TEXT(picklist),4)), 
     VALUE(MID(TEXT(picklist),4,2)), 
     VALUE(LEFT(TEXT(picklist),2)))
```

Comment: can you give me the exact formula? because This is not working. You are right that my format is wrong,